# IntelliJ + groovy DSL: How to exclude files from being compiled by groovy plugin?

Tags: java, groovy, intellij-idea, liquibase, groovydsl

I am working on a Java web project that uses Liquibase groovy DSL to managae DB changes.
For the sake of this topic, it could be any other 3rd party library that uses `*.groovy` files as sources.
The project is built with gradle.
In one of my modules (`dao-base`) under the `src/main/resources` folder I have groovy files (`changelog01.groovy, master_changelog.groovy` etc.). these files should be loaded by the liquibase jar at runtime.

Now when I try to make the project in IntelliJ it gives the following error message:

> Groovyc: Cannot compile Groovy files: no Groovy library is defined for
>   module 'dao-base'.

I understood that the groovy plugin detects `*.groovy` files, tries to compile them and unsurprisingly fails. these are groovy DSL files that should be loaded only by the 3rd party liquibase parser and I don't need IntelliJ's groovy plugin to try and compile them.

I managed to come up with 2 partial solutions:
1. disabling groovy plugin in intellij.
The problem with this solution is that the gradle plugin depends on the groovy plugin and thus is automatically disabled when disabling the groovy plugin. I need the gradle plugin enabled.
2. excluding the `src/main/resources` folder in project settings --> modules --> `dao-base` (my module) --> sources tab.
The problem with this solution is that when I build the project and deploy to tomcat, the files from the resources folder are missing and since the files in it are required in runtime, I get file not found exception when the war loads.

I was hoping someone could come up with a better solution for this problem.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try removing the groovy file suffix from the compiler's resources list:

Settings -> Compiler

[image: IntelliJ IDEA Compiler Settings]

Comment: Thanks. This solved my problem. It's simple but somehow I had overlooked this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you generating the IntelliJ project with the [Gradle Idea Plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/idea_plugin.html)? If so, you can add those groovy files to the compiler resources list in IntelliJ via gradle by adding this to build.gradle:

```
idea {
  project {
    // customize the .ipr file generation.
    ipr {
      withXml { xmlProvider ->
        def project = xmlProvider.asNode()

        // Add appropriate groovy files to the compiler resources. These files will not be compiled by the groovy compiler but will be copied to the classes directory during compilation.
        def compilerSettings = project.component.find { it.@name == 'CompilerConfiguration' }
        compilerSettings.wildcardResourcePatterns*.appendNode('entry', [name: '*/changelog*.groovy'])
        compilerSettings.wildcardResourcePatterns*.appendNode('entry', [name: '*/master_changelog.groovy'])
      }

    }
  }
}
```

This is nice because you will not have to remember to do this manually when you generate the project from gradle.

Answer (score -1):

I was facing same issue. I disabled groovy plugin from setting after that successfully compile as well as executed my project.

Comment: It would also disable Gradle features in IntelliJ. Bad idea.